# Popover view controller is displayed stretched and not resized

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I'm trying to display a view controller with modal presentation style - popover.
The problem is that the view controller is displayed stretched and not resize itself to fit the preferedcontentsize i set.

This is my code for displaying the view controller :

```
let vc = self......
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
vc.delegate = self
let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(360,291)
popover!.sourceView = self.topBarView
popover!.delegate = self
popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0,145,0,0)
popover?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = CustomUIPopoverBackgroundView.self
self.presenetViewController(vc,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

The CustomUIPopoverBackgroundView has this relevant code:

```
override class func contentViewInsets () -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0)
}
```

I will update the post with a screentshot to illustrate what is the problem.
If you need any additional details please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that the PopOver presentation style is not supported on iPhone since the horizontal size class is Compact (Landscape orientation on iPhone6+/S is an exception).
As mentioned in the documentation of UIViewController:

> - UIModalPresentationPopover
>     In a horizontally regular environment, a presentation style where the content is displayed in a popover view. The background content is dimmed and taps outside the popover cause the popover to be dismissed. If you do not want taps to dismiss the popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property of the associated UIPopoverPresentationController object, which you can get from the popoverPresentationController property.
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

Comment: Ok, i tried just using fullscreen option, but the view controller is displayed stretched  and cover full screen intead of just part of it. any ideas?

Comment: I'll ask again - are you on iPhone?
If you are then Popover presentation is not the solution for your problem since it is not supported on iPhones.